# How to automatically open an input file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

In my program written in C++, I open a file as follows:

```
std::ifstream file("testfile.txt");
```

This usage can handle the scenario where the input file has a fixed name of "testfile.txt".
I would like to know how to allow the user to input a file name, e.g., "userA.txt", and the program automatically opens this file, "userA.txt".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a variable. I suggest finding a good introductory [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you're not clear on what they are yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// ...

std::string filename;    // This is a variable of type std::string which holds a series of characters in memory

std::cin >> filename;    // Read in the filename from the console

std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());    // c_str() gets a C-style representation of the string (which is what the std::ifstream constructor is expecting)
```

If the filename can have spaces in it, then `cin >>` (which stops input at the first space as well as newline) won't cut it. Instead, you can use `getline()`:

```
getline(cin, filename);    // Reads a line of input from the console into the filename variable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain command line arguments with `argc` and `argv`.

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // argv[0] is the path to your executable.
    if(argc < 2) return 0 ;

    // argv[1] is the first command line option.
    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);

    // You can process file here.
}
```

The command line usage will be:

```
./yourexecutable inputfile.txt
```

Comment: That should be `char* argv[]`, or even better `char const* argv[]` ;-)